# Transition from intern to permanent staff

Tags: internship, malaysia

I am interning in an Actuarial Consulting firm and will end around March this year. I intend on securing a job in the same firm as the internship is my final semester. How do I approach my supervisor and let her know of my interest in continuing in the firm?

Comment: A country tag could help, as the culture can differ wildly depending on where you're from.

Comment: They will likely talk with you around the end of your internship, and it's up to them to offer you the job. If not, ask them. But you should count with the possibility that they may not want you, so prepare for backup plans ahead in time. You may even use that as leverage if you do it smartly.

Comment: Should I apply for other job opportunities now just in case?

Comment: @AshRaj Yep, it's never a bad idea to keep your options open so apply elsewhere as well. This not only covers you in the event that the job falls through at your current company it also may give you an option you prefer or even potentially leverage in securing a better offer from your internship company.

Answer (score 3):

> How do I approach my supervisor and let her know of my interest in
>   continuing in the firm?

You ask her for a few minutes of her time.

Then, you just tell her that you'd like to stay on with the company and ask if that would be possible.

It's just a conversation.

Answer (score 2):

As an intern, you are expected to be looking for permanent work.

If I were you I would take the direct approach. Let your boss know you're very interested in joining the company permanently at the end of your internship.  Then ask for your boss's advice about how to do that.

Have this conversation soon. That way you and your boss have time to do the paperwork of joining permanently.

And, yes, of course, look for other jobs at the same time. Again, it is not disloyal or impolite for interns to look for permanent work.

(We recently lost a really good intern to another company because we didn't know he wanted to work for us. We should have asked him, yes. But he should have told us too.)

Comment: Great post.  I feel like putting every word of it in bold.